# The push notification doesn't work in multiple sending ios apns Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, apple-push-notifications

I send notification to users one by one in one connection. But users doesn't receive push. This is my code

```
int port = 2195;
        String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";


        string certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Path/Cert.p12");
        string certificatePassword = "password";


        // Encode a test message into a byte array.  

        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                null
        );

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Default, true);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        foreach (var item in db.Devices)
        {


                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command  
                writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)  
                writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)  
                String deviceId = item.device1;
                byte[] b0 = HexString2Bytes(deviceId);
                writer.Write(b0);

                String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"I like spoons also\",\"badge\":14}}";

                writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)  
                writer.Write((byte)payload.Length); //payload length (big-endian second byte)  

                byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
                writer.Write(b1);
                writer.Flush();
                byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                sslStream.Write(array);
                sslStream.Flush();



        }

        // Close the client connection.
        client.Close();
```

If I create connection to send each push, users receive the push. How can i send notification to multiple device?